# How can I merge different binary files with Git?

Tags: git

While working on a project with 2 friends, we decided that for a VCS we would use Git. The program we used, Gamemaker 8.1, has no internal support for any VCS whatsoever. We decided to press on, however due to communication errors we now have   three separate binary files, each with entirely separate work. In using Git with Gamemaker before, I know that it does work as long as the files are properly named and we all work on ONE file. We need, at the end, only one file, preferably with most or all of the work for each member. What ways are there that I can merge these three files, (or even only 2) which all contain very different work, and lose the least amount of work possible? We can't resolve conflicts manually, since the files are binary.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. That would imply that the diff engine could turn the binary code back into source, merge that, and convert it to binary again. It's like asking to merge a .gif depicting a red bus and a .gif depicting a blue bus into a .gif depicting a purple bus. If gamemaker has a way to export code as text you could try merging that.

Comment: Does Gamemaker produce those binary files? If yes, does it have some comparision feature built-in?